# Looping inside an array object

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, reactjs

I'm using [react-select](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select) and want to loop through an object to represent it as the select's value and label:

```
// Inside the component's render:

var myVar = [
  this.props.foo.forEach(function(a){
    {value: a.name, label: a.name} // line 83
  })
];

//return

<Select ref="stateSelect" options={myVar} simpleValue clearable={this.state.clearable}
  name=""
  value={this.state.bar} onChange={this._myFunc} 
/>
```

`this._myFunc` is not relevant for this question. I want to get something like this:

```
var myVar = [
  {value: "hello", label: "world"},
  // the list goes on
];
```

With the above code, I got:

> Parse Error: Line 83: Unexpected token :

I'm not that strong with JavaScript to figure out this solution but is this possible? Links to read up on?

Comment: `{ ... }` is considered as **block** here. Probably you need `someObj = {value: a.name, label: a.name}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you intend to initialize `myVar` with an array of objects from `this.props.foo` then try

```
var myVar = this.props.foo.map(function(a){
    return {value: a.name, label: a.name} ;
});
```

Comment: Failed propType: Invalid prop `option` of type `array` supplied to `Option`, expected `object`. Check the render method of `Select`.

Comment: @Sylar are you still getting `Parse Error: Line 83: Unexpected token :` ? what were you expecting to get as an output from this statement?

Comment: Getting error as in my first comment. In my question where `the list goes on` that's what works but I need the value and label from an array.

Comment: @Sylar can you share a fiddle?

Comment: SORRY! I was wrapping your answer inside: `var myVar = [ //your answer]` It works. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The best is loop in render fct like this:

```
render (){
 return (
  <div>
   <Select
     ref="stateSelect"
     options={
      this.props.foo.map( (a) => {name: a.name, label: a.name} )
     }
     simpleValue
     clearable={this.state.clearable}
     name=""
     value={this.state.bar}
     onChange={this._myFunc} 
   />
  </div>);
}
```

Comment: Is this es6? "Fat arrow"? Maybe useful in other projects.

Comment: Yes es6 with jsx. You can use in es5 map( function(a)  { return {name: a.name, label: a.name} })